# Debug settings on Asp.Net production

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have set `debug=false` in `Web.config` for production, but I wanted to see the exception line number in log so I had to do the following:

- Uncheck `Optimize code`
- Uncheck `Exclude generated debug symbols`
- Set debugging information to `Pdb-only`

My question is do I lose some performance by doing this? And is it recomended to do this on production environment?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's already clearly answered in the asp.net docs.

Answer (score 0):

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-debugging-for-aspnet-applications?view=vs-2017

```
Important

Debug mode greatly reduces the performance of your app. For best performance, set debug="false" in the web.config and specify a Release build when you deploy a production app or conduct performance measurements.
```